# tag a specific value (column) in treeview python to color it

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter, treeview

Does anyone know if i can tag a specific column in treeview python.
I have a dataframe which should be shown in treeview but i want to color some columns, so is that possible to do?
the code:

```
trv = ttk.Treeview(df_frame, show="headings")
# Set The Header of the columns
trv["column"] = list(data_frame.columns)
for column in trv["column"]:
    trv.heading(column, text=column)
data_frame_rows = data_frame.to_numpy().tolist()
for column_nr, row in enumerate(data_frame_rows):
    trv.insert("", "end", values=row)
```

so any ideas ?

Comment: Did you know there is a `tags` keyword argument to `insert()`

Comment: yes i did but if i use it here then rows will be taged but i want to tag the columns.

Comment: But you are inserting rows...? Anyway `heading` does not have `tags` but it has `commands`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tag a column or an individual cell. Tags (and thus, colors) can only be applied to an entire row.